# Object doesn't teleport according to the random range limits

Tags: unity-game-engine, random

I tried making a button to teleport somewhere on a map when I press it, I used Transform.Position() and Random.Range() to teleport the button on the x and y axis.

The expected result was that the button will teleport somewhere between (800, 350) and (-800, -350) because those are the numbers I put in the Random.Range(). But somehow the button sometimes teleports as y < -350 and x < -800. the button also never has a positive x or y position.

I even tried to make the range only positive and 0, but the button is still on negative x and y position(HOW?). I have code here below can someone tell me what is wrong?

Unity itself doesn't show any error.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class OnClick : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text scoreText;
    public int score = 0;
    public void Teleport()
    {
        score += 1;
        transform.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(-800, 800), Random.Range(-350, 350));
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the button is a `child object`. If so then what you are looking at as position in the editor is the `local position` but what you set with the code is the `world position`. Putting the higher-level objects on `(0,0,0)` will make the local and world position the same for this object.

Comment: It may work but the only parent the button has is the canvas, and I can't move the canvas. Is there any way I can change the canvas's position(It is currently on x =960 and y =540). btw thanks for the help!

Comment: There is no need, just work with `world position`. What I am saying is what you see in the editor is local position that is why it is different.

Answer (score 0):

For a UI element positioning, make sure to set the object's anchor correctly.